# Convert a dict stored as a string to byte

Tags: python, dictionary

I have been using osmnx for a project and have attempted to export the resulting dicts to csv using Python 3 using the following code:

```
with open('dict.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for key, value in mydict.items():
       writer.writerow([key, value])
```

Unfortunately, I receive the error:

```
a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

The code that is generating the dict is:

```
mydict = {num:list(streets_per_node.values()).count(num) for num in range(max(streets_per_node.values()) + 1)}
```

I have tried to hunt down the solution, but I fear either the answer is either too simple or too unusual to find in typical tutorials.

Comment: What is `streets_per_node.values()`?

Comment: @MooingRawr That is a result from a series of osmnx calculations. In short, it is a count generated from a networkx multidigraph. The code is long, but the pertinent code that generates the final dict is:

`edges = non_self_loop_edges + self_loop_edges`
`edges_flat = list(chain.from_iterable(edges))`
`counts = Counter(edges_flat)`
`streets_per_node = {node:counts[node] for node in nodes}`

Edges are a graph theory term that, in this case, refers to streets, and nodes are intersections. Full code starts on line 330 here: https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/master/osmnx/stats.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`open('dict.csv', 'wb')` tells Python you want to open the file for writing *bytes*, not text, which is why you get that error. Just omit the `b` and it should work.

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples

Comment: It's a good idea to provide `encoding` too to ensure file encoding is consistent across platforms (Pre Py3.6)